# React pass prop to other component to delete from state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am working on a todo application to understand the power of react. I created 3 components, which I will show you below. So I would like to delete an todo from an array state which is located in an other component.

Take a look at my components below.

This is my TodoAppComponent:

```
import AddTodoComponent from '../AddTodoComponent/AddTodoComponent';

class TodoAppComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                        <h1 className="m-b-md">What needs to be done?</h1>

                        <AddTodoComponent></AddTodoComponent>
                    </div>                         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoAppComponent;
```

Here I have the TodoItemComponent:

```
class TodoItemComponent extends Component {
  deleteTodo(todo){
      console.log('deleteTodo', todo);
      this.props.onDelete(this.props.todo);
  }



  render() {
      console.log('this.props.todo', this.props.todo);

return (
    <div>            
        <li className="list-group-item todo-item">
            <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-md">
                <span className="fa fa-check"></span>
            </button>
            {this.props.todo}
            <span className="pull-right">
                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-xs">
                    <span className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
                </button>

                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle" onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this.props.todo)}>
                    <span className="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </div>
);
```

}
}

export default `TodoItemComponent`;

```
class TodoItemComponent extends Component {
  deleteTodo(){
    // this.setState({
    //   data: update(this.state.data, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
    // })
    console.log('deleteTodo', this.props.todo);
  }


  render() {      
    console.log(this.props.todo, this.props.title);

    return (
        <div>            
            <li className="list-group-item todo-item">
                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-md">
                    <span className="fa fa-check"></span>
                </button>
                {this.props.todo}
                <span className="pull-right">
                    <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-xs">
                        <span className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle" onClick={this.deleteTodo}>
                        <span className="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </li>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItemComponent;
```

Here is the AddTodoComponent:

```
import TodoItemComponent from '../TodoItemComponent/TodoItemComponent';

class AddTodoComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todo: '',
            todoArray: []
        };
    }

    addTodo(e){
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
        this.state.todoArray.push(<TodoItemComponent todo={this.state.todo} onDelete={this.delete}></TodoItemComponent>);
    }

    delete(index){
    //     this.setState({
    //         todoArray: update(this.state.todoArray, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
    //     });

        console.log('testDelete', this.state.todoArray);
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (            
            <div>
                <div className="input-group m-b-md">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Todo..." value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-react" type="button" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)}>Add</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.todoArray}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTodoComponent;
```

As you see I try to log `this.props.todo` when clicked on the delete button, so when it emits the `deleteTodo function` in TodoItemComponent. Where it returns me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null` but in the `render()` method it is recognized and logs the outcome of the input.

Thereby I tried to bind the prop in the deleteTodo function in the `TodoItemComponent`:

```
            <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle" onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this.props.todo)}>
                <span className="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
            </button>
```

So the function looked like this:

```
deleteTodo(todo){
      console.log('deleteTodo', todo);
      this.props.onDelete(this.props.todo);
  }
```

Could somebody help me out on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `onDelete={() => this.delete(1)}` or some other index?

Comment: You can't access the value of `this.props.todo` inside the `delete` method. So, you have to provide a context for it like this `onClick={this.delete.bind(this, this.props.todo)}`. With this, you can access the todo item in your `delete` custom method.

Comment: You should not store rendered React components in state. Store plain old JavaScript Objects and Arrays in state and only render React components in `render`. The `addTodo` method is going to cause problems with rendered Components being pushed into an Array that is updated outside the `render` lifecycle.

Comment: @RossAllen thanks how would you do this?

Comment: @RossAllen Is this what you mean? I can't access the `this.state.todoArray`  in the `delete()`. It returns me this: `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'todoArray' of undefine`

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the misuse of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) here:

```
onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this.props.todo)}
//                            ^ you're binding todo as the context
```

The first argument should be the context of the bound function, i.e. `this`, not the todo.

```
onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this)}
```

And you should use `this.props.todo` within the `deleteTodo` function (which now has a proper context).

Alternatively, you can [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (which maintains it's outer context) to pass the `todo`:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteTodo(this.props.todo)}
```

and your `deleteTodo` method would receive the `todo` as its first argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, and now I log the prop in both components. But when I try to update the state in AddTodoComponent it throws me this error:
`uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'todoArray' of undefined`

Comment: In every other function `this.state.todoArray` is recognized except for the `delete()` than it could not even log the state..

Answer (score 1):

Store data in `this.state` and only create React elements in `render`, something like the following:

```
class AddTodoComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todo: '',
            todoArray: []
        };
    }

    addTodo(e){
        this.state.todoArray.push(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ todo: '' });
    }

    delete(index){
        console.log('testDelete', this.state.todoArray);
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (            
            <div>
                <div className="input-group m-b-md">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Todo..." value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-react" type="button" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)}>Add</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.todoArray.map((todo, index) => (
                      <TodoItemComponent todo={todo} onDelete={this.delete.bind(this, index)}></TodoItemComponent>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the todo prop is not showing correctly that is the value of the input field.

Comment: This only shows up when the `onChange` method is triggered.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want it to do.

Comment: The `todo prop` is not working properly it has to show inside the `TodoItemComponent` as you can see It is the input value. But now it only gets triggered on the `onChange` method.

Comment: So first I gave the `todo prop` this with `this.state.todo` so It can be rendered in the `TodoItemComponent` but when I use your code I can't acces the `todo prop` so the todoItem returns empty.

Comment: I hope you understand what I mean because I totally lost it here

Comment: What is `this.props.todoArray` for if you always want to display `this.props.todo`?